# Configure web app to display an index page in JBoss 7 (with Maven)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, jboss7.x

I am trying to get my JBoss web application project to land on a simple index page. It's a Maven managed project.

The index page consists of a form that the client can input a name. Then JAX RS returns the clients name to screen.

I am not sure if my configuration is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your index page in `src/main/webapp`, say `index.html`, and add the following to your `web.xml`:

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. Perfect answer

Comment: I think placing `index.html` in `src/main/webapp` should be enough as its common to servlet containers, and JBoss 7, to include `index.html` (and derivatives) to be already configured as welcome files. What worries me though is that the example contains the stanza for JSF and I doubt `index.html` will work if JSF is employed to render the form.

Comment: Thanks Jacek, I thought the JSF may conflict with the html

Comment: It won't but if you use JSF you would need to process the pages with the FacesServlet. It however won't influence where files should be in the project and then in the web app.